# sql sum case datewise

Tags: sql, sum, case

I have a table with following feilds.

```
Field1   Field2    Field3    Filed4 
Date     Trantype  AssetType Amount
01/01/18 Pur      EQU       100
01/01/18 Sal      EQU       50
02/01/18 Pur      EQU       100
02/01/18 Sal      EQU       50
```

Output Required

```
Date   Total Purchase    Total Sale  Net Pur Amount 
01/01/18 100              50           50
```

I want to Sum datewise and net off pur and sale for each date. There can be multiple trantype like PURF, PUR etc for PUR and SALF, SAL for Sale. So i have used case statement to net off.

```
SELECT 
       sum(CASE 
           WHEN tran_type in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
           ELSE 0
       END)/10000000 AS Purchase
       , sum(CASE 
           WHEN tran_type not in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
           ELSE 0 
       END)/10000000 AS Sale
, sum(CASE 
           WHEN tran_type in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
           ELSE -1*nett_val 
       END)/10000000 AS Net_Purchase 
,sum(CASE 
           WHEN tran_type not in ('DPURF') THEN nett_val
           ELSE -1*nett_val 
       END)/10000000 AS Volume
   FROM Deal where rectype = 'L' and value_date >= '01 Jul 2017' and value_date <= '31 Jul 2017' and asset_type in ('EQU','ETF','PRF','CCD','AT1')
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have commented but seems my reputation is not high enough. Your example does not correspond to the sample data where names do not correspond.

From the SQL It look like you have a table Deal with columns rectype, value_date, asset_type, tran_type and nett_value. In the example table you suppied different fieldnames and also less fields.

You mention you want results grouped by date, I guess "value_date" but the output only has 1 row whereas you sample table has 2 distinct dates?

The SQL also results in 4 result columns but no date.

With the information you give I can suggest adding the value_date to the select part and add a "GROUP BY value_date" to the end of the query.

I'm not sure why you have the "Sales result column using a NOT IN clause since -- from the sample data I would think it would be an in with ('Sal')

So my query might not be directly what you need but it does use the proper syntax:

```
SELECT 
    value_date
    , sum(CASE 
       WHEN tran_type in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
       ELSE 0 END)/10000000 AS Purchase
    , sum(CASE 
       WHEN tran_type not in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
       ELSE 0 END)/10000000 AS Sale
    , sum(CASE 
       WHEN tran_type in ('PUR','PURF','ISPUR','BONPUR','CONPUR','PMALL','INJVSP','CUSTTO','DPURF','ISDPUR','MFALL') THEN nett_val
       ELSE -1*nett_val END)/10000000 AS Net_Purchase 
    ,sum(CASE 
       WHEN tran_type not in ('DPURF') THEN nett_val
       ELSE -1*nett_val END)/10000000 AS Volume
FROM Deal 
WHERE rectype = 'L' and value_date >= '2017-01-01' and value_date <= '2017-12-31' and asset_type in ('EQU','ETF','PRF','CCD','AT1')
GROUP BY value_date
```

I changed the where filter for value_date to include all of 2017 but that filter will need to change. It is safer to supply fixed date in YYYY-MM-DD format by the way.

Comment: Thanks Johan Bennik. The SQL worked the way i wanted.

Comment: Johan If I want to Group by Months-Year instead of individual dates what should i do?

Comment: if you need the distinction of WEEK and YEAR I would replace `value_date` in the select part with `DATEPART(WEEK,value_date) as WW, datepart(YEAR,value_date) as YYYY` and then change the `value_date` in the group by with something similar: `DATEPART(WEEK,value_date), datepart(YEAR,value_date)`

or if you don't need separate week and year columns you could do: 

`cast(DATEPART(YEAR,value_date) as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+cast(DATEPART(WEEK,value_date) as varchar(2)),2)`

Comment: i get an invalid identier for DATEPART

Comment: Sorry: you should not replace value_date in the WHERE clause, that is used for selecting records, only the SELECT part and GRPU BY should be changed